# Custom Wake Word with Speech SDK

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking for a way to have an application just process voice commands every time I say a specific phrase. The behavior should be similar to Cortana, Alexa or others. The application will be deployed on a hands-free device, but the Speech device SDK cannot be used, because it runs solely on a PC.

Is there an addition to the Speech SDK with a custom wake word yet?

Answer (score 0):

MS speech recognition uses RESTful APIs to cloud services. You can use them from any device.

You can use speech-to-text and voice command services on Android or iOS.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/?v=18.05: Examples exist for both Java and Objective-C.

I think you also want to check out the preview of speaker recognition.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/home

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would need to go to a [specific site](https://cris.ai/customkws) to set a wake work as it's still in preview mode. That will generate some files that you'd download for the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-devices-sdk-qsg).

There's more in [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-devices-sdk-create-kws).